# Loose gear shifter on a 2004 Nissan Pulsar

Tags: car, shifter

The gear shifter is loose on my 2004 Nissian Pulsar, I've tightened it up twice before but seems to come loose every 6months or so and is starting to annoy me.

Any advice on fixing a loose gear shifter and getting it to stay tight for longer than 6 months?

Comment: What gets loose? Nyloc nuts or loctite can help. Does depend on the operator: Chewbacca yanking on it or someone deft and gentle...